# Set environment variable before running a custom action in WiX

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have to build an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)-based installer using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) and I need to set environment `MY_HOME` before running a command action.

I have a component:

```
<Component Id="SEMYHOME"
           Guid="*my guid*">
    <CreateFolder />
    <Environment Id="MY_HOME"
                 Action="set"
                 Part="all"
                 Name="MY_HOME"
                 Permanent="no"
                 System="yes"
                 Value="[APPLICATIONPATH]myapp"/>
</Component>
```

Then I have a custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallMyService"
              Directory="INSTALLDIR"
              ExeCommand='&quot;[INSTALLDIR]myapp\install_service.bat&quot; install'
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="ignore"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="InstallMyService"
            After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

NOTE: This action need the `MY_HOME` variable to be set before running.

When install this MSI, I got a log showing that the `MY_HOME` variable is set before running the custom action "InstallMyService", but the command to install my service still fails. I found that the cause is when command called, MY_HOME still not set.

After an install is finished, MY_HOME was set as expected, but the custom action fails :(

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Installer and Custom Actions are hosted via the Service Control Manager which has a long history of not respecting broadcast messages that are sent announcing Environment changes.   So even if you fix the immeadiate / deferred problem that Yan mentions you'll find that your custom action still doesn't have the environment variable.

Why don't just just pass "[APPLICATIONPATH]myapp" to your .bat file and fetch it in as %2?

BTW I also don't reccomend calling batch files from an installer.  It's fragile and embarrassing to see installs that run popping up little black windows.

Comment: No problem. BTW, one of my punch lines at work is "The 1980's called and they want their environment variables back." :)

Comment: BTW, take a look at the WiX Quiet Exec Custom Action extension.  It's a fairly decent way to mitigate many of my concerns concerning calling EXE's and BAT's in installs.  It'll silence the DOS window and provide logging of the output into your MSI log.

Answer (score 3):

You CA is immediate. This means that it runs immediately when Windows Installer is processing your MSI package. And this obviously happens before the component containing `<Environment/>` is  installed. Modify it to be deferred (`Execute="deferred"`) and schedule before InstallFinalize.

Comment: This didn't work for me.